# How to show that $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$ converges uniformly on $[a,\infty], a>0$, using mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis

My attempt was that  $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} - x \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$ , then by squeeze theorem $sup| f_n(x)  -f(x)|$ tends to 0. So it converges uniformly. However, I do not use mean value theorem. Where am I wrong? There must be a reason the condition excludes the point 0.

Comment: The inequality $\sqrt
{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$ is wrong.

Comment: What do you want to prove? uniformly convergence for $\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ as in the tittle, or $\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}-x$ as in the post

Comment: As in the title, but I do not know why my argument is wrong.

Comment: I don't know how you got the estimate. Rationalizing the numerator gives us a different estimate, and we need to use the fact that $x\ge a\gt 0$. Alternately, the MVT gives a similar estimate.

Comment: $x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2} \leqslant (x+\frac{1}{n})^2$

Comment: Your estimate is simpler than mine, and works.

Comment: Actually, $\sqrt{x^{2} + \frac{1}{n^{2}}} \to |x|$ uniformly on the entire number line, and this can be shown using nothing but algebra.

Comment: Yes, the thing confuses me is that the condition avoids the point 0 intentionally, and it asks us to prove it by using MVT.

Comment: I looked at the rationalizing numerator and MVT estimates again, and they also yield $\le 1/n$, with no restriction on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

By the uniform limit theorem, it is sufficient to prove that $f_n$ is uniformly continuous for all $n$.

So you want to show that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0:|y-x|<\delta \implies  |f(y)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ for any $x,y \in [a,\infty]$

MVT: Let $b \in (x,y)$. Then $\exists c \in (x,y):f(y) - f(x) = (y-x)f'(c)$.

Take $f$ to be your given function. By MVT, for some $c \in (x,y)$, we get $|f(y)-f(x)| = |y-x|f'(c) < \delta f'(c)$; we need this quantity to be less than $\epsilon$.

Therefore, taking $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{f'(c)}$ satisfies the definition of (non-uniform) continuity, but we can do better: $f'(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}}} $ is bounded above by $1$. In particular, we can simply choose $\delta=\epsilon$ and we are done.

Also note that since $a>0$, $f'(c)$ is bounded below by $f'(a) > 0$, so you don't have to bother with possibilities of $|y-x|<\delta \implies |f(y)-f(x)| < 0$. (At least that's my guess with trying the MVT way, as $f$ is indeed uniformly continuous on entire the real line.)

EDIT: but on second thought, the MVT says that $c \in (x,y)$ and not $[x,y)$, so perhaps the $a>0$ restriction is really just superfluous, and a symmetry argument can prove uniform continuity on $(-\infty, \infty)$ as well...)